# Where is mono's log file?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

I'm having an issue with a program crashing on mono, I have an idea why but I can not confirm it as I can not find the log location for mono on ubuntu. I'm developing on windows however I'm deploying to a ubuntu server. So my question is, where is the standard log location for mono on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a log file so I ended up opening a terminal in the file location and running mono via the terminal so the mono terminal wouldn't close straight away